# Прямое использование WinAPI и использование аналогичных .NET методов

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Часто вижу вопросы, как ускорить тот или иной алгоритм, на что я вижу ответы :

"Использование WinAPI позволяет ускорить алгоритм".

Справедливо ли это?

Ведь, все .NET методы являются удобной оберткой над WinAPI и , на мой взгляд, кому, как не microsoft виднее, как выжать максимум производительности из своего api?

Собственно это наводит на меня сомнения.

Comment: _чтобы узнать какая лошадь быстрее, нужно устроить скачки_

Comment: _"все .NET методы являются удобной оберткой над WinAPI"_  и наверное не спроста.

Comment: Ради удобства могла быть принесена в жертву производительность.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, согласен, однако, я не верю, что можно получить что-то быстрее более 10-20%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinAPI - неуправляемый код. Неуправляемый код работает быстрее чем управляемый. Но есть одно очень важное НО - **неуправляемый код работает быстрее управляемого тогда и только тогда, когда используется правильно и по назначению**.

.NET действительно предоставляет множество удобных оберток для нативного кода WinAPI и не только. Эти обертки отчасти позволяют избавиться от необходимости писать много проверочного когда руками и снизить порог вхождения для начинающих программистов, а также уменьшить количество работы опытным программистам, там где не нужно выжимать 100% производительности из железа. На ассемблере можно написать программу, которая выжмет из железа все до последней капли, но для этого потребуется значительно более высокие квалификация разработчика, время на разработку и бюджет проекта, поэтому обычно ниже уровня С/C++ не опускаются даже там, где нужен максимум производительности.

Поэтому прежде чем менять вызовы .NET классов на вызовы WinAPI стоит пройтись профайлером по проблемному коду и выяснить что именно снижает производительность. В большинстве случаев окажется, что проблема вообще не касается ни WinAPI, ни оберточных классов. К тому же если учесть весьма скромную документацию на WinAPI, то не имея серьезного опыта работы с ним, вы скорее получите еще большую просадку в производительности, десяток непонятных багов и, как следствие, кучу дополнительного времени на все это безобразие, как часто говорят - "выстрелите себе в ногу".

Сначала нужно выжать максимум из архитектуры и алгоритмов программы, а потом, если этого окажется мало, смотреть в сторону замены управляемого кода на неуправляемый.

Разумеется все это мало касается проектов и программистов изначально работающих с неуправляемым кодом.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это не всегда справедливо.

Канонический контрпример — класс [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx), который при обычном использовании [быстрее на порядок](https://habrahabr.ru/post/91027/) прямой обёртки к WinAPI-event'у [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

(Разница в том, что `ManualResetEventSlim` несколько циклов ожидания перед тем, как передать управление в ядро. Во время этого ожидания с большой вероятностью оно окончится, так что в этом случае выигрыш налицо.)